# Efficiently sampling large number of rx observables together

Tags: rx-java

I have a large number of observables, and want to aggregate these into a single value. They updated with high frequency, and take it as given that a 'lossy' back-pressure strategy must be used. I've chosen `sample` but anything similar would be acceptable. **I would like to know what the most efficient (performance and/or resource wise) way of doing this is**. Two approaches are obvious:

```scala
val list : Iterable[Observable[Double]] = ???
val f : (Double,Double) => Double = ???
(Observable combineLatest list) sample (1 second) reduce f
```

or alternatively

```scala
combineLatest (list map (_ sample (1 second)) ) reduce f
```

I think it's fair to say this is a very common use-case. To make this less abstract, imagine I have many temperature sensors that emit data continuously. These would be the elements of my `list`. They produce the temperature in SI units, and I want to calculate the average temperature (this is `f`). I also want to have a choice as to display the result either in degrees Celcius or Fahrenheit.

1. Which of the two approaches above (any other suggestions welcome though) would be more efficient space/time wise?
2. Say I wanted to display not only the average temperature, but also the individual (possibly converted) temperatures too. Does that affect the answer?
3. Would your answer change if the Observables came from different sources (e.g. observed on separate threads) vs whether they came in a single serialized stream (e.g. result of a `groupBy` operator on a single observable).
4. Bearing in mind what I say above about back-pressure, would your answer vary if this requirement was dropped (i.e. no need to re-sample).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No; I've moved on from RX. I think this requires a specialized data structure, despite being a common pattern. It's not that it's difficult to implement this (as I've suggested above), but the hard bit is doing it with a monadic/collection-like interface. Look at https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `as` operator can be useful here. In my case, I don't just have a bunch of observables; I have a bunch of things that *have* observables. So first I created a helper class to associate each thing with its observable:

```
public class Pair<K, V>{
    private final K mKey;
    private final Observable<V> mValues;

    public Pair(final K key, final Observable<V> values) {
        mKey = key;
        mValues = values;
    }
    public K key() {
        return mKey;
    }

    public Observable<V> values() {
        return mValues;
    }
}
```

Then I created an `ObservableConverter` that converts an `Observable<Pair<K,V>>` into an `Observable<Map<K,V>>`. It will periodically emit a map containing the latest `V` from each `K`:

```
public class MapLatest<K, V> implements ObservableConverter<Pair<K, V>, Observable<Map<K, V>>> {
    private final PublishSubject<Map<K,V>> mPub = PublishSubject.create();
    private final Map<K, V> mMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Observable<Map<K, V>> apply(final Observable<Pair<K, V>> pairs) {
        pairs.subscribe(this::subscribe);
        return mPub;
    }

    private void subscribe(final Pair<K,V> pair) {
        final K k = pair.key();
        pair.values().doOnNext(v -> mMap.put(k, v)).doOnTerminate(() -> mMap.remove(k));
    }
}
```

My "things" are players and I want to periodically build an R-tree of their locations. So I pair the players with their location observables and then apply `MapLatest`:

```
players.map(player -> new Pair<>(player, player.location()))
    .as(new MapLatest<>()).subscribe(...);
```

Note that I didn't show any code in `MapLatest` that actually emits anything. I'm considering various ways to do that:

- Construct `MapLatest` with an `Observable<?>` and emit whenever that observable emits.
- Construct `MapLatest` with a `Predicate<V>` that returns true when it should emit.
- Give `MapLatest` an `emit` method and trigger emissions externally.

Also note that the `Observable<Map<K,V>>` is never terminated. For my purposes, that's intentional.